# How do I find the correlation between how close the average of historicals are to my current year of data, on a monthly basis

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table and I would like to see the correlation between the average of the historicals in 2019-2022 in the month of January, to the actuals from 2023 in the month of January. I would like the correlation to be taken across the entire timeframe, so January to April. Here is a mock-up of my data below.

| Year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |
| 2020 | 7 | 14 | 28 | 14 |
| 2021 | 56 | 51 | 3 | 30 |
| 2022 | 55 | 61 | 34 | 44 |
| 2023 | 20 | 23 | 12 | 16 |
| Average | 32 | 35.25 | 21.25 | 28.25 |

Ultimately, I would like to create and show this as a stacked bar chart with a correlation line going across. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A correlation would require two columns / arrays of the same size, but here you are wanting to compare to a single value (2023 Actuals). It might help to recast your question as trying to find the probability that the value from 2023 lines up with the historical amounts for that month, in which case you could use a t-test, most likely 2-tailed. Steps would be as follows:

**1. Create t-values.** This would be the (2023 actual - historical average) / (historical standard deviation).

**2. Calculate probability** for positive and negative t-value.

prob_1: `T.DIST(t_value, COUNTA(A1:A4) - 1, TRUE)`

prob_2: `T.DIST(-t_value, COUNTA(A1:A4) - 1, TRUE)`

Where `COUNTA(A1:A4)` is outputs the number of historical years. This should generate 2 values for each month.

**3. Take absolute difference of calculated probabilities**; i.e., prob_3 = `ABS(prob_1 - prob_2)`. This is the probability that the 2023 value is not consistent with the historical data, so take `1 - prob_3` for your final answer. Not exactly a correlation, but it may give you the type of information you are looking for.

For this data, this would look like the following, where "prob_final" would be the value analogous to a "correlation":

| Year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |
| 2020 | 7 | 14 | 28 | 14 |
| 2021 | 56 | 51 | 3 | 30 |
| 2022 | 55 | 61 | 34 | 44 |
| 2023 | 20 | 23 | 12 | 16 |
| t-value | -0.441726104 | -0.503933197 | -0.687705415 | -0.984208286 |
| prob_1 | 0.344294236 | 0.324493673 | 0.270519017 | 0.198791866 |
| prob_2 | 0.655705764 | 0.675506327 | 0.729480983 | 0.801208134 |
| prob_3 | 0.311411528 | 0.351012654 | 0.458961965 | 0.602416267 |
| **prob_final** | **0.688588472** | **0.648987346** | **0.541038035** | **0.397583733** |

As for presenting it as a bar chart with the line going through it...let me strongly recommend against doing that, as it will probably require too much additional explanation, not to mention requiring multiple y-axes.